# Confidence Intervals for incidences

Tags: python, confidence-interval

I can calculate incidence (IR) without problems. With 1000 individuals under risk and 100 events the IR is 100 per thousand.

Somebody told me it is possible to calculate confidence intervals for an IR. But I do not see how and do not understand how this makes sense because the IR is not an estimate but a fixed/real value.

Asking the search engine of my trust I find a lot about incidence ratios (IRR) etc but not incidence. Ant very interesting even on that Cross Validated plattform there is no tag for `incidence` but `incidence-rate-ratio`. Maybe this make sense?
https://www2.ccrb.cuhk.edu.hk/stat/confidence%20interval/CI%20for%20single%20rate.htm

Filling out the fields it gives me a 95%CI between 0.0830324 and 0.1204349.

But I am also not able to reproduce the formula on that website with pythons `math` package.

Maybe I totally misunderstand here something?